# Mutt with GPG Password Protection

Tags: linux, email, encryption, gnupg, mutt

I got Mutt working with the default IMAP password management configuration with this line in my config:

`set imap_pass = XXXX`

Which is obviously not secure. I looked at this

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mutt#Passwords_management
and
http://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-users@mutt.org/msg36375.html

For guidance on how to encrypt the data. Neither solution worked for me though. The Arch linux one seems ideal because I would rather not use a wrapper everytime I start Mutt.

I did `gpg --gen-key` and set name to `John Doe`, email to `JDoe@example.com` and comment to `XXX`.

I created a file with this data

`set EMAIL_PASS = random30digitpassword`

I tried encrypting my file with

`gpg -e -r "John Doe" ./password`

Now if I want to decrypt it should just work without a prompt because I am the one with the keystore but alas if I execute this following command it still prompts for a password

`gpg2 -dq password.gpg`

Not only did that not work but with this as my Mutt config:

```
source "gpg2 -dq /home/John/password.gpg | "

set folder      = imaps://lavabit.com/
set imap_user   = JohnDoe@lavabit.com
set imap_pass   = $EMAIL_PASS
set spoolfile   = +INBOX
```

It complains that that path does not exist (and no password prompt comes up)

So I am pretty much stumped because it isn't working from two angles. Any ideas?

Comment: Wrong board. Try super user

Comment: Sorry about that. Wasnt aware of the super user board.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but someone else may have this problem too. Try removing the space from between the quote and the pipe. It worked for me.

```
"gpg2 -dq /home/John/password.gpg |"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mutt manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#set-myvar), user-defined variables should always have the `my_` prefix.  So, rename `EMAIL_PASS` with `my_email_pass` both in the encrypted file and in `.muttrc`.

Also,  what happens when you type `gpg -dq /home/John/password.gpg` from the command line?  Does it decrypt the password file?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @ooesili 's answer (which debugs the code in the original question and also helped me get started), to fully benefit from `gpg` to avoid typing passwords all the time in `mutt`, it may be useful to set up `gpg-agent` to keep a cache of its passphrase for a more or less long time.

In Linux, this is done by editing `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and adding a couple of lines like

```
default-cache-ttl 360000
max-cache-ttl 360000
```

The numbers represent timeout of the cache in seconds.